# Update multiple fields from float to integer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, integer

I want to update more than 100 fields from a shapefile from data type float to integer in QGIS. I know that the tool "Refactor fields" exist, but is there a faster way to do this?

It is slow because I need to change the datatype manually in the tool interface for more than 100 fields. The processing time of the tool itself is indeed fast enough.

Comment: What is the data container? Shapefile? Geopackage?

Comment: @til_b shapefile, I edited my question

Comment: How is refactor fields not fast enough?

Comment: @Erik It is slow because I need to change the datatype manually in the tool interface for more than 100 fields. The processing time of the tool itself is indeed fast enough.

Comment: This sort of operation will take 200 times longer if you go one column at a time. Much better to define the new schema in an empty shapefile, then copy all rows at once.converting as necessary on the fly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use PyQGIS. Just change the first two lines of the code to your needs and run it:

```py
inputlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('mylayer')[0]
fieldstoskip = ['field_to_skip_name_1','field_to_skip_2', 'field_to_skip_n'] # list of float-fields you do not want to convert to integer

mapping = []
for field in inputlayer.fields():
    changetoint = False
    if field.typeName() == 'Real' and field.name() not in fieldstoskip:
        changetoint = True
        print('Will change field ' + field.name() + ' to type integer')
    fmap = {'expression': ('round(\"'+field.name()+'\",0)' if changetoint else field.name()),
           'length': field.length(),
           'name': field.name(),
           'precision':(0 if changetoint else field.precision()),
           'type': (4 if changetoint else field.type())
           }
    mapping.append(fmap)

params = {'FIELDS_MAPPING': mapping, 'INPUT': inputlayer, 'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
refactored = processing.run('native:refactorfields',params)['OUTPUT']
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(refactored)
```